# Nginx gives blank pages - 500 error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

After resizing my Server's RAM and rebooting, every thing was normal, but the website on nginx gives blank white page, i didn't detect any "Error logs"

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    access_log /var/www/mysite/application/app/logs/access_log;
    error_log /var/www/mysite/application/app/logs/error_log;
    root /var/www/mysite_ch/application/web;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/version-(\d+)/(.*)$ /$2 break;
        try_files $uri /app.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config|apc-.*)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

for the php file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 750 May 24 16:20 /var/www/mysite/application/web/app.php
```

**edit:** I used Chrome console to check the returned code, which is "500".

Comment: I checked the response code is 500!!, and my doc root isn't blank, I dumped my config files as i couldn't find any error log describing the issue.

Comment: a 500 is a server error - if you haven't found an error message, you're looking at the wrong log file(s).

Comment: Unfortunately there was no error logs in my site's log and not in nginx, and not even on "syslog", i found out that mysql wasn't running at all, after starting it up, it was fixed, thanks for your consideration :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was receiving "500" returning code error, i checked my running services, i found that "mysql" daemon wasn't running, after starting it up, my site was running normally again.